# How to best expand HTML table in the middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am dynamically creating an HTML table by using a repeater. I have four columns that I fill with some company data and what I want to do is to be able to click on a row and add another row with a google map and some more data in another repeater. When I click on the row again I collaps the extra row and I can click on another customer row.

My first repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSearchByNameResult" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="Result">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>VAT No</th>
                    <th>Entity Name</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td class="expandResult" title="Click for more information">&#43;</td>
                <td class="vat"><%# Eval("VAT.identifierValue")%></td>
                <td class="vat">
                    <%# Eval("Name.organisationName")%>
                    <%# Eval("Name.fullName")%>
                    <%# Eval("Name.tradingName")%>
                    <%# Eval("Name.primaryName")%>
                </td>
                <td class="location">
            <%# String.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("location.postCode"), Eval("location.stateCode")) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        </FooterTemplate
 </asp:Repeater>
```

and my google map after (which I hide/show with a click event on expandResult class).

```
        </div>
            <div id="map_canvas"/>
        </div>
```

As you can see I show the map at the bottom of the result which is not ideal when the list is very long so I want to show it (and the other repeater) betweeen rows. How should I do this? I know how to insert a new row with jQery but the table has four columns and I want the extra row to only have two. Must I then break the table and insert a div instead and start a new table just after with the rest of the data? Skip tables altogether? I would like to keep tables though for sorting purposes.

Any example on where this is done elsewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using colspan ? .. You can combine using the colspan attribute in your  . Something like this would work for you

```
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><div>Your map goes and it will take the whole space </div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `colspan` attribute of the new column you're setting. i.e. Total columns are 4 per row. You want just 2 for this row so each column would have a `colspan=2` like this:

```
<td colspan="2">whatever</td><td colspan="2">whatever</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loose the `<table>` structure and just work with `<div>` elements.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="dataItemRow">
        <div class="vatItem expandResult" title="Click for more information">
            &#43;</div>
        <div class="vatItem vat">
            <%# Eval("VAT.identifierValue")%></div>
        <div class="vatItem vat">
            <%# Eval("Name.organisationName")%>
            <%# Eval("Name.fullName")%>
            <%# Eval("Name.divadingName")%>
            <%# Eval("Name.primaryName")%>
        </div>
        <div class="vatItem location">
            <%# Sdiving.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("location.postCode"), Eval("location.stateCode")) %>
        </div>
        <div class="mapSpace hidden">
            <div>Your map goes and it will take the whole space</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The use CSS to apply the style to each element you want, but make sure the style for "vatItem" and "hidden" styles looks something like:

```
.vatItem
{
float:left;
width:24%; //or a fixed number that insures that the four items create a 'row' no more or less..
}
.hidden
{
display:none;
}
```

with that in place you use jquery/javascript to assign a function to the expandResult class which makes all of the mapSpace items 'hidden' then locates the one mapSpace inside the same div and remove the hidden class from it. (so that it shows up)